# Clear modal content when hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have this code and dont know how to reset content and in this case is youtube. When close and open another, it's the same video.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  /* Get iframe src attribute value i.e. YouTube video url
  and store it in a variable */
  var url = $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src');

  /* Assign empty url value to the iframe src attribute when
  modal hide, which stop the video playing */
  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', '');
    // remove the bs.modal data attribute from it
    $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
    // and empty the modal-content element
    $('#modal-body .cartoonVideo').empty();
  });

  /* Assign the initially stored url back to the iframe src
  attribute when modal is displayed again */
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://thietkemenunhahang.com/jsvideomodal.js"></script>

<!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
<a href="#myModal" class="xemvideo" data-toggle="modal">XEM VIDEO</a>

<!-- Modal HTML -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="1024" height="768" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/g_ETwB2rhXMvq" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Not working. Anyone can help me ? :(

Comment: I try many answer and not work :(

Comment: From where you are getting the updated URL???

Comment: I try, when close and open new modal. Content not showing bro. Demo this: https://thietkemenunhahang.com/
Js: https://thietkemenunhahang.com/jsvideomodal.js

Answer (score 0):

you can clear Iframe like this:

```
     $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {   
           var iframe = document.getElementById("cartoonVideo");
           iframedoc =iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
           iframedoc.body.innerHTML = '';
      });
```

and set new 'src' in 'show.bs.modal' event

```
<a href="#myModal" class="xemvideo" data-toggle="modal" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/pbQ2k4Q8y0o">XEM VIDEO 1</a>
<a href="#myModal" class="xemvideo" data-toggle="modal" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/d46GppZFjbc">XEM VIDEO 2</a>    


 $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
        var btn = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var url= btn.data("video");
        $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src', url);
  });
```

Comment: It's show error: Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin .... How to fix this bro ?

Comment: You can't access an <iframe> with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it. For the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) browsers block scripts trying to access a frame with a different origin.